# {!SObject.fieldName} sometimes doesn't work?

Tags: visualforce

My SObject is a packaged one and in my VF page I have queried the object with all related fields. In the VF page:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, $#,##0.00}">
    <apex:param value="{!InvoiceObj.FTR__Invoice_Order_Due__c}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Doesn't seem to be working. But only some of the fields - the others work fine. I used `System.debug()` to look at the related field value and they are fine. And if I use a parameter in the controller to record down `invoiceObj.[FiledName]` and use that value in the VF page everything will just be fine. But is there any reason behind this? It seems really strange to me.

Comment: Any errors you are getting?

Comment: @highfive I don't get any error. It's just blank inside. When I debug through developer tool in browser, it just looks like <td> </td>

Comment: Have you tried out `<apex:outputText value="${0, number, #,##0.00}">` ? i.e. the `$` sign is at the start

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It's because of field level security. After setting that it is all good now.